# Tried to create a simple map where the player can move around, failed miserably

Tags: c, dictionary

So whenever I run this code I end up with a screen full of random symbols, and when I try to move the player the program crashes. I've been stuck for quite a while trying to solve it and any insights would be extremely appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int size, x, y, test = 1;
printf("How big is your map? ");
scanf("%d", &size);
char map[size][size], move;
int row = size/2, col = size/2;
for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    { //gives one value to everything in the board
        for(y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            map[size][size] = 'X';
        }
    }
while(test != 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &test); //just so I can keep testing over and over
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < size; y++)
            if (x == row && y == col)
            {
                printf("O");
                map[row][col] = 'O';
            }
            else
                printf("%c", map[x][y]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Use W, A, S, D to move around.");
    scanf(" %c", move);
    map[row][col] = 'X'; //set the old player location to the original value.
    switch(move)
    {
        case 'w': 
        case 'W': row -= 1; break;
        case 's':
        case 'S': row += 1; break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A': col -= 1; break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': col += 1; break;
    }
    map[row][col] = 'O';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your map initialisation loop: ` map[size][size] = 'X';` You want the iteration variables x and y here. Generally speaking: Separate your code into functions (init map, print map, move one step, ask for direction), and better get rid of a dynamically sized array on the stack (this is called variable length array and not actually part of the C language) .. it could easily overflow your stack.

Comment: `map[size][size] = 'X';` --> `map[x][y] = 'X';` and perhaps more similar mistakes because after this gaffe you only ever set `map[row][col];`. the reason you get crap on the print is that other elements are uninitialised. The first mistake, is also *undefined behaviour* indexing outside the array limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        map[size][size] = 'X';
```

should probably be

```
        map[x][y] = 'X';
```

and

```
            map[row][col] = 'O';
```

should be

```
            map[x][y] = 'O';
```

Also, protect row and col from getting outside of [0,size]

... Also, change

```
scanf(" %c", move);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &move);
```

Writing characters to to whatever the existing value of move points to is causing the crash.

Comment: Oh. Wow. I suddenly feel extremely stupid. Okay, thanks a lot. But I still can't get my O to actually move, and yes I'm going to get to the row and col from getting outside [0,size] but for now I just want to actually make the O move. It's for my project which is due 2 months from now and I wanna make some early progress. Seriously though, thanks. Jesus, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @JonnRalgeYuvallos if you have other problems, correct these mistakes, sleep on it, try again and ask another question.